# Why is there a race when calling QThread.quit() and subsequently QThread.wait()?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, qthread, pyside2

Using `PySide2`, I have an auxiliary thread running a background event loop. Upon closing my app, I'd like to `quit()` the auxiliary thread and `wait()` for it complete its events.

However, my app has a deadlock (or something) as soon as I call `wait()`.  To demonstrate this issue, I have created a small sample app with a subclassed `QThread` that runs an event loop by calling `exec_()` and then simulates a long quit time with some mock cleanup prints.

```py
import sys
import time

from PySide2.QtCore import QThread
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class AuxThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print("Starting AuxThread")
        self.exec_()
        print("Stopping AuxThread")
        iteration = 0
        # Simulate a long time for thread finish
        while iteration < 100:
            iteration += 1
            print(f"{iteration} cleanup loops in {QThread.currentThread()}")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.thread().setObjectName("main thread")

        self.aux_thread = AuxThread()
        self.aux_thread.setObjectName("aux thread")

        self.aux_thread.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print(f"Quitting aux_thread from {QThread.currentThread()}")
        self.aux_thread.quit()

        # Increasing this time allows the run() function to complete
        # If this time is too short, then execution hangs forever
        time.sleep(0.001)

        print(f"blocking thread {QThread.currentThread()}")
        self.aux_thread.wait()
        print(f"aux_thread is joined")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output of this function is shown below, the number of printed iterations will differ according to the timing.

```
Starting AuxThread
Quitting aux_thread from <PySide2.QtCore.QThread(0x7fcc9cfd12b0, name = "main thread") at 0x11c4f1580>
Stopping AuxThread
1 cleanup loops in <__main__.AuxThread(0x7fcc9cfe5e40, name = "aux thread") at 0x11c4f15c0>
2 cleanup loops in <__main__.AuxThread(0x7fcc9cfe5e40, name = "aux thread") at 0x11c4f15c0>
... [output elided] ...
72 cleanup loops in <__main__.AuxThread(0x7fcc9cfe5e40, name = "aux thread") at 0x11c4f15c0>
73 cleanup loops in <__main__.AuxThread(0x7fcc9cfe5e40, name = "aux thread") at 0x11c4f15c0>
blocking thread <PySide2.QtCore.QThread(0x7fcc9cfd12b0, name = "main thread") at 0x11c4f1580>
```

The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QThread.html) say that `QThread.wait()` "blocks the thread until the QThread has finished execution (i.e. when it returns from `run()`)"

Interestingly, they don't mention which thread is blocked here, but it can't make sense to block the QThread that you're waiting on. I think `aux_thread.wait()` should only block the main thread, why is execution in the aux thread blocked as soon as `wait()` is called?

What am I missing?

Comment: You are calling `aux_thread.quit()`, so it's quite clear which thread is meant. `aux_thread` is **not** the main thread. Btw. usually you don't want to block the main thread :)

Comment: actually, I am attempting to block the closing until the `aux_thread` is finished. The question is about why `aux_thread.wait()` is blocking the `aux_thread` _and_ the `main_thread`

Comment: It blocks the thread on which the `quit` and `wait` are called, in this case the main thread. Because it's waiting for all operations of your `aux_thread` to finish. If there are no specific results you need to wait for, you could call just `quit`. It shouldn't block the `aux_thread`, it just exits as soon as it can (if you mean why it doesn't output to 99).

Comment: According to the docs, `aux_thread` should not be blocked. But in the example I've given it is blocked when I call `aux_thread.wait()` The program never exits, it hangs forever on the wait call